# transfering itunes library win-> mac - is it possible?

Tags: itunes, mac, windows

I'm about to order one of the new macbook airs and wanted to know if it is possible to transfer my itunes library from my old windows machine to the mac. I know you can do win->win and mac->mac, but can you do win-> mac? If so, how?

With the music I'm not too concerned with play-counts and ratings, I just want the music, album and cover-art.
With the apps, I know I could share them with a "new" itunes library but would have to purchase them again if I need to update. Is there a way to circumvent that and make my new itunes library my "main" one?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: just copy the iTunes folder from the Windows machine to the mac.  It works fine, I did it myself last year with no problems.

Longer answer with more details at http://www.macworld.com/article/146958/2010/03/move_itunes_windows_mac.html

Answer (score 0):

Just copying the iTunes folder to a HDD will probably be simplest, but if you don't have a ton of music, and you want to transfer some documents and photos you could use migration assistant over your home network.
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4796

Never done it that way myself but migration assistant is generally a pretty good tool.